# Excel Formula returns "Refers to empty cells"

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010, conditional-formatting

I am using this formula for a running balance:

```
=IF(AND(ISBLANK([@[EHEAP AMOUNT]]),ISBLANK([@CREDIT])),"",R1-[@[EHEAP AMOUNT]]+[@CREDIT])
```

`EHEAP AMOUNT` is the debit column, `CREDIT` is credit
and `R` is the balance column.

There must be an error in my conditional formatting because my entire balance column is flagged with "The formula in this cell refers to cells that are currently empty." Can anyone help clear this error?

Comment: Does the formula work outside of conditional formatting?

Comment: Does the formula refer to cells that are currently empty?

Comment: Yes the formula works without the IF statement

Comment: Yes cells are empty, but isn't the purpose of the conditional formatting to stop calculations until the cell has data

Answer (score 0):

Your formula is saying "if EHEAP AMOUNT and CREDIT are ***both*** blank,
then display blank, otherwise do the calculation." 
So that means if (only) one of the input values is blank,
the `IF` does the calculation (using the blank term). 
You probably want

```
=IF(OR(ISBLANK([@[EHEAP AMOUNT]]),ISBLANK([@CREDIT])),"",R1-[@[EHEAP AMOUNT]]+[@CREDIT])
    ↑↑
```